# How to extract specific text from a webpage?

Tags: java, text, extract, html

I'm trying to extract a specific text from a webpage?

This is the part of the webpage which contains the specific text:

```
<div class="module">
<div class="body">
<dl class="per_info">
<dt>F.Name:</dt>
<dd><a class="nm" href="http://">a Variable Name1</a></dd>
<dt>L.Name:</dt>
<dd><a class="nm" href="http://">a Variable Name2</a></dd>
</dl>
</div>
</div>
```

How to extract the content of Variable Name1 and Variable Name2?

Is there any html parser could do this extraction?

Comment: +1: Finally there's someone who asks for a *parser* to parse HTML instead of asking for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

well, you can try Selenium, it loads the html page to your java code in a DOM-aware fashion, such that afterwards you can pick content of HTML elements based on id, xpath, etc.

http://seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 0):

[TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) is a SAX-compliant parser that is able to parse HTML found in the "wild". So there's no need for well formed XML.

Answer (score 0):

[jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is a Java library that can parse HTML and extract element data.  To use jsoup, first you create a jsoup Document by parsing it from a file, URL, whole document string, or HTML fragment string.  A HTML [fragment](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-body-fragment) example is something like:

```
String html = "<div class='module'>" +
    "<div class='body'>" +
    "<dl class='per_info'>" +
    "<dt>F.Name:</dt>" +
    "<dd><a class='nm' href='http://'>a Variable Name1</a></dd>" +
    "<dt>L.Name:</dt>" +
    "<dd><a class='nm' href='http://'>a Variable Name2</a></dd>" +
    "</dl>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
```

With the document, you can use jsoup's [selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to locate specific elements:

```
// select all <a/> elements from the document
Elements anchors = doc.select("a")
```

With the element collection, you can iterator over the elements and extract their element contents:

```
for (Element anchor : anchors) {
    String contents = anchor.text();
    System.out.println(contents);
}
```